# Ruby on Rails error when parsing XML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I get this error now when parsing XML's using my Ruby on Rails server:

```
ERROR -- : exception while processing events: undefined method 

`content' for nil:NilClass Backtrace
-- /var/www/distribution/distribution-server/app/models/upload_action.rb:23:in `block in upload'
-- /var/www/distribution/distribution-server/app/models/upload_action.rb:14:in `each'
-- /var/www/distribution/distribution-server/app/models/upload_action.rb:14:in `upload'
-- /var/www/distribution/distribution-server/app/services/run_listener.rb:8:in `block in start'
```

The relevant code:

```
def self.upload(xml_files)
actions = []

xml_files.each do |xml_file|
  if File.exist?(xml_file)
    doc = File.open(xml_file) { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }

    action = UploadAction.new
    action.file_name = [doc.xpath("//field[@index='103']").first.content]
    action.content_provider_name = doc.xpath("//field[@index='45']").first.content
    action.content_provider_title = doc.xpath("//field[@index='24']").first.content
    action.created_date = doc.xpath("//field[@index='13']").first.content.to_date
    action.credit_line = doc.xpath("//field[@index='91']").first.content
```

The error occurs on the third line of 'action', action.content_provider_name. All required fields in the XML are correctly filled out. If I change `doc.xpath("//field[@index='45']").first.content` to a string, like 'Example String', then action.content_provider_title has the error.

**Edit**

Partial Example of XML Fields:

```
`<metadata>
<field index="24" type="picklist" 
name="content_provider_title">title</field>
<field index="45" type="picklist" 
name="content_provider_name">name</field>
<field index="79" type="text" name="Monitor State">Restored</field>
<field index="81" type="checkbox" name="Confirm Delete">false</field>
</metadata>`
```

Comment: So, the problem is that `doc.xpath("//field[@index='45']").first` is `nil`, it would be nice if you put the xml_file that's causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of Rails you use, you can change the following line to one of the options below it:

```
action.file_name = [doc.xpath("//field[@index='103']").first.content]
```

Updating to:

```
action.file_name = [doc.xpath("//field[@index='103']").first&.content]
# or
action.file_name = [doc.xpath("//field[@index='103']").first.try(:content)]
```

Both of these options protect against `NilClass` errors. If you don't necessarily need value for `action.file_name`, this will fix the error.

Otherwise, it's a case of ensuring the selector (`doc.xpath("//field[@index='103']")`) is definitely correct (it seems to be, as you're not getting an error calling `first`) and, if so, that there is definitely data in the array it returns.

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Comment: Thank you, my xml's seem like they're parsing successfully with no errors as yet